# Unable to use the different domain credentials in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2019

I can't change the username in the SQL Server Management Studio. It's pointing automatically to my last used username and disabled. Any help would be appreciated

[image]

Comment: Please post error messages you get, and commands you use.

Comment: @Sachith the error message is -> the security database on the server doesn't have a computer account for this workstation trust relationship

Comment: please update your question with error message.

Comment: @Sachith I've updated the question with an image! username got disabled and I'm unable to change it. How can I change it?

Comment: Change `Windows Authentication` to `SQL Server Authentication` if it's an SQL Login (as opposed to a domain login).

Comment: https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/windows.html

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't change the user name when you select 'Windows Authentication'. It always defaults to the currently logged in user or the security context of the user under which the program is executed.

So, if you want to use another user credential then use the 'Run As different User' option when opening the SSMS. If you right click on the SSMS shortcut you will get this option.

Answer (score 0):

> It's pointing automatically to my last used username and disabled. Any help would be appreciated

There is nothing wrong in that, as mentioned in comments, you could only change the user when you change authentication type to **SQL Server authentication**. If you insist to change the user in Windows Authentication, hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> (in your keyboard) and right-click on SSMS (shortcut), then choose **Run as different user**

[image]